# Fetch all table name and row count for specific table with Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can i fetch all the table name and row count for the specific table from the specific database ?

Result

```
Table Name , Row Count , Table Size(MB)
---------------------------------------

table_1    , 10        , 2.45

table_2    , 20        , 4.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @temp_table = []
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
      count = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM #{table}").fetch_hash['count']
      size = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '#{table}'").fetch_hash
      @temp_table <<  {:table_name => table,
          :records => count.to_i,
          :size_of_table => ((BigDecimal(size['Data_length']) + BigDecimal(size['Index_length']))/1024/1024).round(2)
        }
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|    
 h = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '#{table}'").fetch_hash
 puts "#{h['Name']} has #{h['Rows']} rows with size: #{h['Data_length']}"
end
```

Comment: Show table status not returning accurate table rows with InnoDB.

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged mysql but you can do it in a DB-agnostic manner via ORM.

```
class DatabaseReport
  def entry_counts
    table_model_names.map do |model_name|
      entity = model_name.constantize rescue nil
      next if entity.nil?
      { entity.to_s => entity.count }
    end.compact
  end

  private

  def table_model_names
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map(&:singularize).map(&:camelize)
  end
end
```

Note that this will skip tables for which you don't have an object mapping such as meta tables like `ar_internal_metadata` or `schema_migrations`. It also cannot infer scoped models (but could be extended to do so). E.g. with `Delayed::Job` I do this:

```
  def table_model_names
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map(&:singularize).map(&:camelize) + ["Delayed::Job"]
  end
```

Comment: This is the correct way of doing this. I would change `entity.all.count` to `entity.unscoped.count`. Removing the `all` stops it loading all the records into memory and adding `unscoped` removes any default scopes that may skew the numbers.

Comment: `all` is just a scope, it doesn't run a query until you interact with it further. `all.count` creates a count query and doesn't load all entries. `entity.count` would also work though. Default scopes are usually there for a reason so I wouldn't mess with that in a generic SO response. (Btw, default scopes should be avoided altogether, rubocop even included a rule when I asked them: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rails/issues/76)

Comment: Im not sure what `all` exactly is under the hood. But you are right it is lazy loaded. After 
it has been interacted with and loading occurs. It loads _every_ database object into memory. You don't need every database object in memory to perform a count of the number of rows. `.count` doesn't do that. It just performs a plain old `count(*)` on the table. While it is true that default scope is generally frowned upon. It has a use within the framework. i.e. soft deletion and its nice to account for that.

Comment: As mentioned, `entity.all.count` does not load all entities. It executes a `COUNT` query. Same as `where().count`.

Comment: Its the Rails version. Im using a fairly old version and it _does_ load everything into memory.

Comment: Gotcha. I edited it to `entity.count`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with my own version which is also db agnostic.

As it uses the descendants directly it also handles any tables where the `table_name` is different to the model name.

The rescue `nil` exists for cases when you have the class that inherits from ActiveRecord but for some reason don't have a table associated with it. It *does* give data for STI classes and the parent class.

```
my_models = ActiveRecord::Base.descendants

results = my_models.inject({}) do |result, model|
  result[model.name] = model.count rescue nil
  result
end
```